# can't run javascript that requires gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have installed gulp (gulp --version tells me so) but when I run the code: `var gulp = require("gulp");` it gives following error:

> ./gulpfile.js: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
> ./gulpfile.js: line 1: var gulp = require("gulp");'

Comment: This is hard to answer without more information. How are you running the code? In Node.js? How did you install gulp? What do you get if you run `which gulp` on the command line?

Comment: have you add it to your package.json and install the package itself?

Comment: @fagerbua when I run which gulp it gives: /usr/local/bin/gulp
I installed it with: npm install gulp -g
I have this code in gulpfile.js and then I run it with: ./gulpfiles.js

Comment: @A.Llorente yes

Comment: try to check the gulp installed in global or not

Comment: @JosephStalin It's instaleld globally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second statement in your code block, is that ' after the semicolon there in your source code? If so, remove that and try running the code again, the updated line would appear as such:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
```